# operator precedence && and ||

Tags: java, operator-precedence

- please ignore the question - its wrong

I am not sure if my question is issue is related to operator precedence- Just to rule out that I added additional bracket. My understanding is in that case that code in each bracket will be executed. So basically all the OR operation will happen and its output would be AND'ed to condition a.
I have below set of parameters a = true and c = 254 , b is not availble ( b is initialized to 0 -At any given time either b or c only is availble) . So for the above condition I am expecting if condition to result in true but it's resulting in false condition. Any reason why ? Also what is best way to debug such things as in where exactly condition is going wrong - any pointers

```
if ((a == true) && ((b == 460) || (b == 454) || (b == 455) || 
            (c> 13568 && c< 14335) || 
            (c> 10640 && c< 10655) ||
            (c> 11296 && c< 11311) || 
            (c> 25600 && c< 26111) || (c== 7825)))
```

Comment: The code in each pair of bracket is not *executed*, it is *evaluated*. What do you mean by ' b is not available'? Is it `0` or not initialized?

Comment: When c is 254 and b is "not available" (what does it mean? 0?) then 2nd part of your condition is false then (a == true) && false results in false

Comment: b is initialized to zero

Comment: for a = true, c = 254,
your result of false is correct. what exactly did u expect to evaluate to true in the set of ORs?

Comment: If your question is wrong you should delete it.

Answer (score 1):

For your condition to be true, `a` must be true, and in addition, at least one of the conditions on `b` or `c` must be true.

Therefore, if `a==true` and `c==254`, you will get `false`, since `c` is not within any of the ranges you allow, and, as you said, `b` is not available (which I'm assuming means it doesn't have one of the 3 values you allow).

Comment: yes a is true. no I want the condition to be true only if c == 7825 and not for any number less than

Comment: @oneday Then why do you expect your condition to be true when c is 254?

Answer (score 1):

First `a` is evaluated, if `(a == true)` evaluated to `true`, then only it will execute next `&&` statement

```
((b == 460) || (b == 454) || (b == 455) || 
            (c> 13568 && c< 14335) || 
            (c> 10640 && c< 10655) ||
            (c> 11296 && c< 11311) || 
            (c> 25600 && c< 26111) || (c== 7825))
```

Inside this, it will check for any one condition which is `true`, and once it encounter any one statement `true`, it return from there.

Comment: yes .. so a == true and b = 0 ( initialized value) and c is equal to 254

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler if the code is written in a more readable manner;

```
bool isEqualToAny(int valueToCheck, int[] listToCheckIn){
    boolean isMatch = false;
    (for item in listToCheckIn){
       if (item == valueToCheck){
          isMatch = true;
          break;
       }
    }
}

bool isWithinRange(int valueToCheck, int min, int max){
    return (valueToCheck > min && valueToCheck < max);
}

if ((a == true) 
   && (isEqualToAny(b, int[]{460,454,455}) 
   || isWithinRange(c,3568,14335) 
   || isWithinRange(c,10640,10655) 
   || isWithinRange(c,11296,11311) 
   || isWithinRange(c,25600,26111) 
   || isWithinRange(c,10640,10655)
   || (c== 7825)))
```

In java8 you can use an array of **Tuples** to make #isWithinRange more like #isEqualToAny